# python: Move file to ftp folder shortcut without credentials, possible?

Tags: python, ftp

So I have files on `c:\some_folder`, that I want to move to a folder that is in path `c:\Users\my_user\Desktop\hello_shortcut`, but actually `hello_shortcut` is an ftp folder. It has an address like `192.100.xxx.xxx`. When I copy the address from the toolbar, I get something like `ftp://some-text:some-text@192.100.xxx.xxx`.

I tried using `shutil.move` and setting the destination as the shortcut `hello_shortcut`, but that doesn't work. Although I certainly can simply drag and drop files to this folder **manually**, and they will appear on the server.

Any solutions to this, except getting the credentials? Can I acquire the credentials from Windows itself, seeing as I already have them stored somewhere? or maybe find a way to transfer files to this shortcut folder anyway?

Comment: what is the error you received on `shutil.move()`?

Comment: so `hello_shortcut` is a folder or `.lnk` shortcut?

Comment: @MattR no error, the files simply don't appear in the destination folder.

Comment: @OlegRybalchenko when I right click-it and look at properties it says "folder shortcut". However, doing `.exists` on it in my python script returns `True`.

Comment: @mu無 It is set to move files without auth, yes. If I drag and drop a `.jpg` into it manually, I'm not asked for a password, and the files appear normally.

Comment: @mu無 yeah well that is the essence of my question. Whether it’s possible to utilize my permissions when dragging manually to transfer via python somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Shortcut is not a folder, it is just a file pointing to some object. So you can't use it as a directory while moving file. If the shortcut refers to the ftp shared directory, you can use its real path.

Or, if the shortcut can be modified and you can't rely on the real path, read its target with separate function:

```
import sys
import win32com.client 

def get_target(path):
    shell = win32com.client.Dispatch("WScript.Shell")
    shortcut = shell.CreateShortCut(path)
    return shortcut.Targetpath

get_target("c:\\Users\\my_user\\Desktop\\hello_shortcut.lnk")
```

And then use this path as usual to operate with the file.

Comment: All that's returning is the same string I'm passing to it...?

Comment: "If the shortcut refers to the ftp shared directory, you can use its real path" - I can't really do shutil.move/copy to something like `192.168.xxx.xxx` though, can I?

Comment: now I'm really not sure that I understand you correctly. Can you provide this fragment of code?

Comment: I’m trying to use get_target, passing it the shortcut path, but it’s returning the same string I provide it. (It also expects a .lnk path,and when I append that to my folder name and do ‘exists’ on its path Python returns false).

Comment: so what is the final path passed to `exists`?

Comment: `Path(project_settings.user_home, 'Desktop',project_settings.avidshare_folder).exists()` where `avidshare_folder` is the **shortcut** folder returns `True`.

Comment: and what is the result of `Path(get_target(project_settings.user_home, 'Desktop',project_settings.avidshare_folder)).exists()`? `False`, right?

Comment: get_target() won’t accept that path because it doesn’t end with `.lnk`.